# What is the best way to concat a namespace class static variable?

Tags: php, namespaces

In PHP we can do things like this:

```
$who = 'world';
$a = 'hello ' . $who;
```

or

```
$a = "hello $who";
```

or

```
$a = "hello {$who}"
```

Quoting *Stephen Clay* from php.net into the String operators section the last way is the best because when we use dots PHP is forced to re-concatenate all string. Also if we need to concat more variables, the last is a better way than the second way. 
*But*, Which is the best way if I have to concat a value from a class static variable ?
PHP throws error if you try to concat the variable directly into a namespace class, without using dots. Only the first way shown before is allowed. I want to know if there is some another way to do this

ERROR:

```
$a = "hello \namespace\classname::$who"; //NOTICE: undefined variable who
$b = "hello ${\namespace\classname::$who}"; //NOTICE: undefind variable classname
$c = "hello \namespace\classname::${who}"; //NOTICE: undefine variable who.
$d = "hello {\namespace\classname::$who}"; //NOTICE: undefine variable who
```

I tried to explain with simple code, the really is that I need to concat a static variable from a class who I can't get an instance. If you get some class into a variable and later try to concat the static property this run correctly also

```
$who = new \namespace\classname();
$a = "{$who::$who} $a"; // this run ok.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with something like...

```
$d = "hello {\namespace\classname::$who}"
```

is that the `{}` would normally expect just a variable to do a substitution, but as it sees `\namespace\classname` is wouldn't know if this was a literal piece of text or not, so it defaults to being a literal and then gets to `$who` and so looks for a variable in the current namespace.

If you can't get an instance of the class, you can still set a variable with the name of the class...

```
$class = namespace\classname::class;
echo "Hello {$class::$who}";
```

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the best way if I have to concat a value from a class static variable

The one that works. These are micro-optimizations and usually does not have any measurable impact on performance. Choose the version which is more readable for you and use it:

```
$who = \namespace\classname::$who;
$a = "hello {$who}";
```

or

```
$a = 'hello ' . \namespace\classname::$who;
```

And then focus on more important things. I'm sure your app has plenty places which could be optimized and give some measurable performance improvements, don't waste time on such low-level stuff (unless your app is only concatenating strings :P).